# Multiply a table with a sub-table of another table

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, data, table

Consider two grids of coordinates:

```
grid1 = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 15}, {j, 1, 20}], 1]//N;
grid2 = Flatten[Table[{0.5 i, 0.5 j}, {i, 1, 45}, {j, 1, 60}], 1];
```

`grid2` includes `grid1` as a subset. In my realistic case, the pattern of the sub-set is more complicated than in this toy example.

Next, consider two tables:

```
tab1 = Join[grid1, {Exp[#[[1]]] Exp[-#[[2]]]} & /@ grid1, 2];
tab2 = Join[grid2, {Sin[#[[1]]] Tan[#[[2]]]} & /@ grid2, 2];
```

In my realistic case, they are **pre-computed**, I only know that `tab2` is computed for `grid2` and `tab1` for `grid1`.

I want to multiply the elements of the third column of `tab1` by the elements of the third column of `tab2` for matching values of the first and the second column. I.e., the resulting table should be just `tab1` but where the third column or the `i`th row is replaced by the multiplication of `tab1[[i]][[3]]*tab2[[j]][[3]]`, with `j` belonging to the row of `tab2` with the first and second columns coinciding with those of `tab1[[i]]`:

```
tab3=Join[grid1, {Sin[#[[1]]] Tan[#[[2]]] Exp[#[[1]]] Exp[-#[[2]]]} & /@ grid1, 2];
```

Could you please tell me how to obtain tab3 if having `tab1`, `tab2` precomputed (so we cannot just use the expression above)?

Comment: `(a = (Most@# -> Last@#) & /@ tab1) // Short[#, 4] &
(b = (Most@# -> Last@#) & /@ tab2) // Short[#, 4] &` and `Merge[KeyIntersection[{a, b}], Apply@Times] // Normal /. Rule[List[a_, b_], c_] :> {a, b, c}`

Comment: `(Merge[KeyIntersection[{a, b}], Apply@Times] // Normal) /. 
 Rule[List[a_, b_], c_] :> {a, b, c}` (missed opening parenthesis on comment above, going for a coffee break). Now you can focus on the speed part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
KeyValueMap[
  Append, 
  Merge[
    KeyIntersection[{GroupBy[tab1, Most -> Last], GroupBy[tab2, Most -> Last]}], 
    Apply[Times]@*Flatten]]
```

Comment: (+1) Do you know if there is such a thing as "ValueMap"? I mean, something that acts on the values of associations and not on the keys.

Comment: For most operations that work on lists, if you apply them to associations they automatically work on the values and not the keys.

Comment: So, ValueMap would just be Map.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @lericr!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that every element of `grid1` is contained in `grid2`, then you could do it with `Nearest` as follows:

```
tab1[[All, 3]] *= tab2[[Flatten@ Nearest[tab2[[All, 1 ;; 2]] -> "Index", tab1[[All, 1 ;; 2]]], 3]];
```

Now `tab1` should be equal to `tab3`.